# jQuery Code Hinting in Dreamweaver with noconflict

Tags: dreamweaver, jquery, code-hinting

Currently evaluating Dreamweaver CS 5.5. I like much of it - but wondering about the jQuery code hinting.

I like that feature quite a bit, but problem is, we use the noConflict() feature, like this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

I am wondering if there is a way (built-in, code work-around, hack, or perhaps a plugin of some kind) that will enable the code-hinting to pick up $j() as opposed to $().

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the code hint xml file for jQuery in

Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\configuration\CodeHints

First few lines of the document you'll find  and you need to change alias="$" to alias="$j".